# Use nodeenv with VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

Is there a way to instruct VS Code to use a virtual environment for non-python operations ? The goal is to be able to use a [nodeenv](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv) when opening new terminals or using debugging tools ?

[nodeenv](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv) is a tool allowing to create isolated environment where node ecosystem is installed.

When using nodeenv, npm or other `-g` installed CLI are only available when the environment is activated. So is there a way to configure VSCode to tell it which PATH to use, which virtualenv to activate or where CLI tools are ?

Please note that the idea is to use non-python tools installed via [nodeenv](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv) in a virtualenv, so the `python.pythonPath` VSCode config doesn't work.